# Unable to uninstall or reinstall Ubuntu desktop

Tags: 12.04, wubi, uninstall

The `uninstall-wubi` option doesn't work.

When I try reinstalling it they show an error and tells me to check "wubi 12.04 rev266" log

Everything goes fine till the bottom which shows this:

```
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 81, in select_target_dir
Exception: Cannot install into C:\ubuntu.
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.
05-25 15:20 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
05-25 15:20 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
05-25 15:20 ERROR  root: Cannot install into C:\ubuntu.
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 81, in select_target_dir
Exception: Cannot install into C:\ubuntu.
There is another file or directory with this name.
Please remove it before continuing.
```

What do I do?  I've tried the uninstall wubi option but all it shows is "reinstall using recommended settings which doesn't do anything"

Okay I've tried installing it into another hardrive and I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 117, in create_uninstaller
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\registry.py", line 45, in set_value
WindowsError: [Errno 5] Access is denied
05-26 16:12 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
05-26 16:12 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
05-26 16:12 ERROR  root: [Errno 5] Access is denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 117, in create_uninstaller
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\registry.py", line 45, in set_value
WindowsError: [Errno 5] Access is denied
```

Answer (score 2):

Rename or remove the `C:\ubuntu` directory and run `wubi.exe` again.

As it says in the log:

> Exception: Cannot install into C:\ubuntu. There is another file or
>   directory with this name. Please remove it before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

Open Add/Remove programs in your windows , there will be wubi program installed , uninstall it and try again .

all the best .

Comment: hahaha that was the first thing i tried to do when i got an error popping up. the thing is, it's NOT in the list. everytime i try to reinstall they say that ubuntu exists in my harddrive but i've checked "add/remove programs" a hundred times there isn't any wubi or ubuntu. i can screen shot to prove it. what i'm trying to say is. IS there any alternative way to get rid of it. if it were so easy as to uninstall it using "add/remove programs" i wouldn't be posing this question at all

Comment: the file location of my ubuntu is in my C:\ hardrive but everytime i delete it and try to reinstall it'll reappear and tell me that another ubuntu exists in my hard drive. so yeah. is there any alternatives

Comment: change the WUBI location from C to something else . try it .

Comment: while i'm installing it?

Comment: i tried installing it to another drive.i get this

Comment: i edited the original doc please do take a look

Answer (score 0):

Your uninstall wubi must be run from Windows not from Ubuntu.  (this will remove Ubuntu completely from your system).  Reinstall the Ubuntu desktop:= must be done in the Ubuntu system.

Comment: yeah i did run it from windows why would i run it from ubuntu. but in any case i can't even access ubuntu. like it'll go straight into windows instead of having the option of choosing whether i want to go to windows or ubuntu. even pressing f8 doesn't show anything

Comment: you wrote: "the uninstall-wubi option doesnt work", that means that you have installed ubuntu in Windows.  So if you want to uninstall a program in Windows you have to use the appropriate method for this.  Take care afterwards that the directory C:\ubuntu is removed.  Reboot your computer and reinstall wubi.exe

Comment: i've tried rebooting... i sincerely apologize for being a total imbecile at this because this hasn't occured before. what are the exact steps i'll have to carry out? would it be okay if you listed them out?

Comment: 1. In Windows : download Revo uninstaller (it is for free) and very good. and install it.

Comment: 1. In Windows : download Revo uninstaller (it is for free) and very good. and install it.  2. With revo uninstaller: start it up, search for wubi and uninstall it.  Revo will you ask how strong you will do it.  Take the most strong possibility. Follow the instructions on the screen, and delete if Revo ask for it all the things that are mentioned. (register - files etc.). It is completely safe. 3. in windows explore: take a look if c:/ubuntu is still there.  If so: delete it. 4. Reboot the computer now. 5. Once you are in Windows back, install wubi.exe. 6.  Reboot, and every thing must work